# Using Google OR-Tools Routing Library to model a VRP with a location always occupied by a vehicle

Tags: mathematical-optimization, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I need to model a modified VRP in which there must always be a vehicle available in a given location to respond to an eventual emergency at the remaining nodes.

MY FIRST MODEL
I’m using the c++ ortools routing library.
My modified VRP can be described as follows. (A) There is a set of identical special nodes that represent the standby location. (B) At any time, one (and only one) special node must be occupied by a vehicle. The number of special nodes is equal to the number of vehicles. Thus, each vehicle has the possibility to go to at least one special node.  To ensure (B), I add the following four constraints:

1. Instead of the depot, one vehicle (route) will have one special node as its starting position.
2. The transit cost from one special node to the depot is zero to make this special node the last one visited on its route.
3. SUM({special node slacks}) == MAX({route end times}). // to cover the role horizon time
4. CumulVar(special_node[i]) + SlackVar(special_node[i]) == CumulVar(special_node[i+1]). // no-overlap between special visits

Therefore, any vehicle can start its route normally, go to one (or more) special node(s) at any time to stay there for a while, and then go back to finish its route.

special_nodes = {1, 17, 18, 19}, TW(time windows), S(slack), T(transit = distance(i, next(i)) + slack).

WHAT I HAVE WORKING
The model works perfectly when I set large upper bounds for wait and operation times in the time dimension. (kTimeMax > ~40)

THE PROBLEM I CANNOT SOLVE
When I set lower upper bounds on the time dimension, constraints 3 and 4 seems to be ignored.

I’m open to any suggestion. Thanks.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include "ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h"
#include "ortools/constraint_solver/routing_enums.pb.h"
#include "ortools/constraint_solver/routing_index_manager.h"
#include "ortools/constraint_solver/routing_parameters.h"

namespace operations_research {
    void VrpTimeWindows() {
        // Instantiate the data problem.
        DataModel data;

        const int kSpecialNode{ 1 };

        // Real + duplicated nodes
        const int kNumNodes = data.time_matrix.size() + (data.num_vehicles - 1);

        // Route starts-ends locations
        const std::vector<std::pair<RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex, RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex>>
            starts_ends{
                {RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex{kSpecialNode},   RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex{0}},
                {RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex{0},   RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex{0}},
                {RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex{0},   RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex{0}},
                {RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex{0},   RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex{0}}
        };

        // Create Routing Index Manager
        RoutingIndexManager manager(kNumNodes, data.num_vehicles, starts_ends);

        // Create Routing Model.
        RoutingModel routing(manager);

        // Get pointer to CP Solver.
        Solver* const solver = routing.solver();

        // Create and register a transit callback.
        const int transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(
            [&data, &manager, kNumNodes](int64_t from_index, int64_t to_index) -> int64_t {
                // Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
                auto from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index).value();
                auto to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index).value();
                // callback(kNumNodes-1, depot) = 0.
                auto last_special_node = RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex{ kNumNodes - 1 }.value();
                if (from_node == last_special_node && to_node == data.depot.value())
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                // Any node out of time_matrix equals kSpecialNode.
                if (from_node >= data.time_matrix.size())
                {
                    from_node = kSpecialNode;
                }
                if (to_node >= data.time_matrix.size())
                {
                    to_node = kSpecialNode;
                }
                 return data.time_matrix[from_node][to_node];
            });

        // Define cost of each arc.
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index);

        // Add Time constraint.
        std::string time{ "Time" };
        const int64_t kTimeMax{ 22 };
        routing.AddDimension(transit_callback_index,  // transit callback index
            kTimeMax,   // allow waiting time
            kTimeMax,   // maximum time per vehicle
            false,      // Don't force start cumul to zero
            time);
        const RoutingDimension& time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time);

        // Instantiate route start and end times to produce feasible times.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.num_vehicles; ++i) {
            routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
                time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)));
            routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
                time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)));
        }

        std::vector<int> special_nodes = { kSpecialNode };
        for (size_t i = data.time_matrix.size(); i < kNumNodes; i++)
        {
            special_nodes.push_back(i);
        }

        // Non-overlep between slacks of special nodes.
        // cumul(special[i]) + slack(special[i]) = cumul(special[i+1]) 
        for (size_t i = 0; i < special_nodes.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            int64_t index = 
                manager.NodeToIndex(RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex(special_nodes[i]));
            int64_t next_index =
                manager.NodeToIndex(RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex(special_nodes[i + 1]));
            solver->AddConstraint(solver->MakeEquality(
                solver->MakeSum({
                    time_dimension.CumulVar(index), time_dimension.SlackVar(index) }),
                time_dimension.CumulVar(next_index)
            ));
        }

        std::vector<IntVar*> end_cumuls;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.num_vehicles; ++i)
        {
            end_cumuls.push_back(time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)));
        }

        std::vector<IntVar*> special_node_slacks;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < special_nodes.size(); i++)
        {
            special_node_slacks.push_back(
                time_dimension.SlackVar(manager.NodeToIndex(
                    RoutingIndexManager::NodeIndex{ special_nodes[i] })));
        }

        // sum(special_node_slacks) == max(end_cumuls)
        solver->AddConstraint(solver->MakeEquality(
            solver->MakeSum(special_node_slacks),
            solver->MakeMax(end_cumuls)
        ));

        // Allow access to slack and transit variables after problem resolution.
        for (const auto& slack : time_dimension.slacks())
        {
            routing.AddToAssignment(slack);
        }
        for (const auto& transit : time_dimension.transits())
        {
            routing.AddToAssignment(transit);
        }

        // Setting first solution heuristic.
        RoutingSearchParameters searchParameters = DefaultRoutingSearchParameters();
        searchParameters.set_first_solution_strategy(
            FirstSolutionStrategy::PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC);

        // Solve the problem.
        const Assignment* solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(searchParameters);

        // Print solution on console.
        PrintSolution(data, manager, routing, *solution);
    }
}  // namespace operations_research

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) {
    operations_research::VrpTimeWindows();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3799

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).